# what is tweepy api function to update header photo of twitter profile?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have tried to find tweepy api function to update header photo of twitter profile. But I could not find it.

Does anybody know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need to use is update_profile_banner()

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v2.3.0/tweepy/api.py#L392

Comment: I am getting error when i am trying to update the the profile banner using the script. I am not getting why ??

Comment: @AbdulRehman im trying the same but for the profile pic and I'm getting a 403 error

Comment: @Maverick Do you know how to solve this Error. I even asked about this error at Tweepys official discord but no one is replying there as well.

Comment: @AbdulRehman yes thanks for reminding me :) , I fixed it ill write an answer

Comment: @AbdulRehman https://stackoverflow.com/a/68126651/13749032