# The Error tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy

print("This is a twitter Bot")

apiKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
apiKeySecret="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"

accessToken="1111111111111111111111111111111111111"
accessTokenSecret="222222222222222222222222222222222222"

auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(apiKey,apiKeySecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken,accessTokenSecret)

api=tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('Twitter Bot In Action')
```

Comment: Avoid sharing the apiKey, apiKeySecret, accessToken and accessTokenSecret.

Comment: Did you definitely generate the `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` after you had set read/write permissions on your app dashboard? (note, you should regenerate them now anyway, never share these in public as they can give access to your account)

Comment: **This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803645/403-error-with-tweepy/71951399#71951399).**

Answer (score 2):

Delete the previous app

Get Elevated access

Create a new app

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll want to regenerate your credentials now if you haven't already.

Make sure you're using the correct credentials.
If you're using Essential access, you won't be able to access Twitter API v1.1.

See [the FAQ section about this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-403-forbidden-error) for more information.

For code block usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I was just facing, I have discovered that you must apply to have `Elevated Features` in the twitter developer portal.
It was after messing around with more permissions on the portal that I was met with this error message

`TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve', 'code': 453}]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for Elevated access before using Tweepy, in:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/elevated

Answer (score 0):

line 100, in request
raise Forbidden(response)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.